# Отправляю запрос на сервер, а приходит undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня есть программа на ExpressJS, которая отсылает ошибки с моего сайта в телеграмм.

Я развернул его на Heroku.
Мой запрос:

```
function SendTelegramError(message) {
  let options = {
        weekday: 'long',
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'long',
        day: 'numeric',
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        second: '2-digit',
    }
    let today = new Date()
    let sendData = {
        site: window.location.hostname,
        full_url: window.location.href,
        date: today.toLocaleDateString('ru-RU', options),
        text: message,
    }
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://labtelegram.herokuapp.com/error',
        data: sendData,
    }).then((data) => {
        console.log('Успешно!', data)
    })
}
```

Запрос проходит успешно, ответ возвращается.
Вот NodeJS код:

```
const TelegramApi = require('node-telegram-bot-api')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

const token = ТУТ МОЙ ТОКЕН
const bot = new TelegramApi(token, { polling: true })

app.get('/error', async (req, res) => {
  const { text, site, full_url, date, time } = await req.body
  let newError = `================
<b>⚠️ДАННЫЕ О САЙТЕ⚠️</b>
Сайт: <b>${site}</b>
Страница: <b>${full_url}</b>
Дата: <b>${date}</b>
Время: <b>${time}</b>
Причина ошибки: <b>${text}</b>
================`
  sendMessage(newError)
  res.status(200).json({
    success: 'true'
  })
})

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    success: 'true',
    message: 'Welcome!' 
  })
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:5000')
})

const sendMessage = text => {
    bot.getChat('@labsite_errors').then(response => {
        bot.sendMessage(response.id, text, {
      parse_mode: 'HTML'
    })
    })
}
```

В телеграмм приходит такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что за `await req.body`?

Comment: пробовал сделать так, много чего пробовал, не помогает

Comment: его точно нужно убрать. 
ну и смотреть в network что отправляется, можно попробовать слать постом. и на ноде консолькой глянуть что в req.body есть

Comment: GET-параметры лежат в `req.query`